# How to evolve weights of a neural network using a GA?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I'm working on an assignment and I need to evolve the weights of my neural network.
My neural network is work but I'm unsure of how to evolve my network in a way that will get me good results.

I know my AI teacher said I need to use a sigmoid function and add up my weights*inputs but I'm not exactly sure on the rest.

Thanks.

Edit:
I need to use a GA to train the weights. Sorry I didn't make it clear.

Comment: Please improve your question.  It is way too 'open-ended'.  Are you sure you wish to use GA to evolve the NN... ?   (not that this is necessarily a bad idea, but in the context of an intro class this seems to be be an unnecessary mixing of the genres.   Also, the suggestions from your instructor do no appear to hint at a GA approach).

Comment: Sorry my bad, I thought I mentioned in my question I need to use a GA but I didn't make that very clear. I don't have a data set to train the weights, so that's why I'm using a GA.
The work is an extension to my AI assignment where we are suppose to create a basic GA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are any number of ways to do this, and generally one is not (for homework) just told to go make it happen without being given an algorithm to implement.

One of the common methods taught in an AI or neural networks class is backpropagation:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation

**UPDATE:**  Oh, I see.  Now I can at least point you in the proper direction.  The discussion is a bit long to provide in the answer space on stackoverflow, but the basic idea is to generate a bunch of random neural networks to (very badly!) solve your problem, then apply genetic algorithms to the networks (i.e., convert the neural networks to chromosomes that can be mutated, crossed-over/recombined, etc, according to their fitness) and let the whole system bootstrap itself out of the primordial ooze.  So to speak.

There is a very good paper about one particular application (chess) written by Fogel, et al, here:  http://www.aics-research.com/ieee-chess-fogel.pdf

Comment: Sorry my bad, I thought I mentioned in my question I need to use a GA but I didn't make that very clear. I know about back propagation but in my problem I don't have a data set to train the weights, so that's why I'm using a GA.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to evolve neural networks. You can evolve topologies, weights or both (this is done especially in reinforcement learning domains, see [EANT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_acquisition_of_neural_topologies) or [NEAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroevolution_of_augmenting_topologies)).

You said you should evolve the weights of your network. Generally you can apply any optimization algorithm for this. But there are different categories of problems and optimization algorithms. In supervised learning it usually makes sense to calculate an error on your training set and the gradient of the error function with respect to the weights. Optimization algorithms that use gradient information are usually faster than genetic algorithms (e. g. Backprop, Quickprop, RProp, Conjugate Gradient, Levenberg-Marquardt...).

As you said, you don't have a training set and thus you don't have an error function so you cannot calculate a gradient. Well, what you need to evolve the weights of your neural networks is some kind of fitness function. If you don't have any fitness function, you will not be able to improve anything by adjusting your weights. So, basically you have a function F(w), where w is your continuous weight vector you have to optimize with respect to F. Your algorithm should do something like this:

1. initialize neural network
2. generate N weight vectors
3. calculate fitness values of weight vectors
4. repeat 2.-4. until some stopping criterion is satisfied

From your description I guess that you probably have to solve some kind of reinforcement learning problem. In this case you could e. g. take the accumulated reward of an episode as a fitness value. If you are interested in this topic: there is some recent research about applying genetic algorithms on neural networks to solve reinforcement learning problems (this is called neuroevolution). Usually people use genetic algorithms like CMA-ES ([CMA-NeuroES](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1645634)) or [CoSyNE](ftp://ftp.idsia.ch/pub/juergen/ecml06.pdf).

I hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

The fitness function of your GA should be able to optimize your NN's weights for example solving the logical AND problem with a single layer perceptron requires a function such as this:

**fitness = 1 - (input1*weight1 + input2*weight2)**

The closer your fitness gets to 0 the better, with an optimal solution of (input1*0.5 +  input2*0.5)

if we replace input1 and input2 with values such as and weights of 0.5 on each neuron

> input1 = 1, input2 = 1 => fitness = 0
>
> input1 = 0, input2 = 1 => fitness = 0.5
>
> input1 = 1, input2 = 0 => fitness = 0.5
>
> input1 = 0, input2 = 0 => fitness = 1

These generated
 weights could then be transfered into the indexed weight for each neuron. Essentially you would not be creating many neural nets, but many combinations of weights for a NN and using the GA to optimize them.